# Is this a bug in the for command that matches file names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

How come the following command in a batch matches the korean resx file?

```
D:\code>for /R %f in (sed*) do del "%f"

D:\code>del "D:\code\mmc\build\modules\fcm_sqlautomatedfunctiontests\images\sedonamtnbike.jpg"

D:\code>del "D:\code\mmc\fm.ux\parts\dataworkloadselectableitems\selectableitemscontrol.ko.resx"
```

Comment: `*` at the end mean `*.*` as a quick way of typing `*.*`. It is an MSDos feature. And remember the extension is what appears after the **last** dot. I don't understand what arrogance you have to call it a bug.

Comment: I recreated your directory structure and file names and your code does not match the `.resx` file.